ARM Toolchain build error in Modus Toolbox for PSoC 6 MCU
I'm trying to build a sample project in Modus Toolbox using a PSoC 6 based MCU, which requires the ARM Toolchain instead of GCC_ARM. However, I'm encountering errors during the build process.
I've tried setting various flags in the Makefile to compile the C++ code, but I'm still unable to resolve the issue. The error messages I'm seeing are:
Linking output file mtb-example-sensors-radar-presence.elf
Warning: L6304W: Duplicate input file C:/Users/MadhavS/Projects/TEST/presence-sensor/mtb-example-sensors-radar-presence/build/CYSBSYSKIT-DEV-01/Debug/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.o ignored.
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol _std::__1::__ios_base::__Init (referred from anon$$obj.o).
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol std::__1::ios_base::Init::Init() (referred from ifx_radar_sensing.o).
Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol std::__1::ios_base::Init::~Init() (referred from ifx_radar_sensing.o).
Finished: 0 information, 1 warning and 3 error messages.
make[1]: *** [../mtb_shared/core-make/release-v1.9.1/make/core/build.mk:529: C:/Users/MadhavS/Projects/TEST/presence-sensor/mtb-example-sensors-radar-presence/build/CYSBSYSKIT-DEV-01/Debug/mtb-example-sensors-radar-presence.elf] Error 1
make: *** [../mtb_shared/core-make/release-v1.9.1/make/core/main.mk:434: secondstage_build] Error 2

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue or provide guidance on setting the correct flags in the Makefile for the ARM Toolchain?
Also I am getting a warning about deprecated armasm assembler and to use armclang instead. Tried multiple solutions for that also, But no luck.
Any helps are appreciated
I am expecting to Compile the project using the ARM toolchain instead of GCC_ARM. With GCC_ARM it is building with out any error.
Tried setting multiple options in Makefile changing the LDLIBS, LDFLAGS, CXXFLAGS etc by referring the chat GPT. But no luck there.
Tried multiple workabouts by referring the ARM Documentation , ARM Compiler 6.19 Migration Guide , But No luck
